# Storing and retrieving media files from database c#

Tags: c#, binary

I am trying to build a quiz program fetching the questions from a database and showing them in a visual studio app.
With some of my questions i want to show a picture or a video, so i've added a varbinary(max) field in my table of questions.

But i have no idea what to enter in those fields i've read some articles and saw values like "0x00342" or something similar. How would i get this data? Do i have to make something that converts my file into bytes?
I've read something about 'Filestream' aswell is that worth looking into?

Another question i have is it wise to store my files into my database or should i store the filepath in the database and put the files somewhere else, changing the varbinary into varchar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Binary stored in a database column is called a BLOB (Binary Large OBject).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309158